# aws s3 bucket log monitor?

Tags: logging, amazon-s3

I'm logging all the activity to one of my s3 buckets using [AWS Server Access Logging](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/ServerLogs.html). The logs are stored as text files in another s3 bucket. Does anyone know of a good online service for monitoring and searching these logs?

Comment: Hi have you solved this problem? I'm working on this at the moment.